# error handling openCurrentDatabase in another instance of Access

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba

I have a list of about 400 full filepaths and filenames of access databases.  I wrote a VBA program in Access that that loops through the list, opens each database in a second instance of Access, and pulls out information I need, however some of the filepaths are wrong and result in an error for Access being unable to open the database.

Even though I have an error handler in place to try to handle this, the error handler does not trigger, and instead the code breaks on error.  My options are set to only break on unhandled errors, but this isn't helping.

Is there a way to capture this error that's generated by the appAccess object?

```
Set rstReportList = Currentdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_ReportList")

rstReportList .movefirst

Do Until rstReportList .EOF
    On Error Goto CantRun  '--Never actually triggers

    strDb = rstReportList!Location & rstReportList!FileName

    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strDb  '-- Error 7866 occurs here, code breaks

    For each qdf in appAccess.Currentdb.QueryDefs
        UpdateResults rstReportList!ID, rstReportList!FileName, qdf.name, qdf.SQL, qdf.Type
    Next qdf
    appAccess.DoCmd.Quit
NextReport:
    rstReportList.MoveNext
Loop

Set rstReportList = Nothing
Set appAccess = Nothing

Exit Function

CantRun:
    UpdateResults rstReportList!ID, rstReportList!FileName, "Error", "Error", 999
    Set appAccess = Nothing
    GoTo NextReport
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... some of the filepaths are wrong and result in an error for Access
>   being unable to open the database.

Use `Dir()` to confirm that `strDb` points to a file which actually exists.  And don't attempt to open one which does not exist.

```vb
If Len(Dir(strDb)) > 0 Then
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strDb
    ' ... and everything else you want to do with appAccess
Else
    ' What should happen when the file does not exist?
End If
```

Actually it should be more efficient to do `Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")` just once at the beginning of the procedure and then reuse `appAccess` with the `OpenCurrentDatabase` and `CloseCurrentDatabase` methods.  But that is a different issue --- it has nothing to do with the #7866 error problem you're facing.

Comment: That's a great tip HansUp, thanks!  I think that will solve the issue I'm facing. Still curious to know if it's a VBA limitation of some sort that prevents me from handling the error, or if it is actually possible and I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: OK.  Be cautious about `GoTo`.  What happens if you change `GoTo NextReport` to `Resume NextReport`?